# Some database fields are not saved in sqlite flutter, how to check in DB?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

Some fields are not loading back in flutter app once I save them and load back.
While saving I am able to see the maps, it is correct only.

So, I want to check that load that sqlite db file.

For that, I kept a text field and ran the emulator.
[image: Emulator]
But, when I ran the same on my mobile, it is not showing the db file path.

Can you explain how to get that file from the mobile(Oneplus 8t)?

Answer (score 0):

in android studio you can see the database by going to : view=>tool windows => database inspector